# Query MySQL database across network using command line client?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I am able to successfully connect to the database on my network using JDBC:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ip-address/dbname","uname","password");
```

How can I connect to and query the same database through the MySQL command line client.

Comment: seems like you are using java. What is your question?

Comment: @theunlucky Yes, MySQL 5.5 command line client.

Comment: I would like to query on a db across the network using the MySQL Command Line Client.

Comment: I guess that u are having the permission to access the DB server ,  `mysql -h ipaddress -u root -p` and login with the password , select the DB as `use db_name`, start to query on DB. @Shalin

Comment: @theunlucky I tried that, it gives me an error in syntax everytime.

Comment: I am on WIndows XP and ran it on the MySQL command line client.

Comment: Can u please add the syntax error here ?Shalin

Comment: @Shalin : can you please add the query too

Comment: @theunlucky I am getting the following error - ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: please append whole error statement, Are you using the GUI tool Command line ?@Shalin

Comment: @BhavikShah mysql> **mysql -h ipaddress -u root -p** is what I queried on the command line client. I am able to connect through JDBC using the same ip address, user and pass.

Comment: You cant use this in mysql command prompt  , before getting into mysql command client  you should use this statement ... just open the command prompt and pass this statement  @Shalin

Comment: you are trying to run mysql inside the mysql command-line client.  you need to run `mysql -h ...` from your _command line_.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -h ipaddress -u root -p' at line 1

Comment: Is there any way to query using the MySQL 5.5 command line client, it's not working with the windows command prompt.

Comment: @Shalin : what are you trying to do by  `mysql -h ipaddress -u root -p` this is not even a query. In the cmd line you have to type queries like `SELECT``UPDATE` etc.

Comment: Are you using  Mysql Workbench Client Tool ?@Shalin

Comment: @theunlucky I am using MySQL Server 5.5's Command line client. It's just a plain command line client like the Windows cmd.exe

Comment: What happens when you use  the above command  in command.exe ??? @Shalin